# Get injector from module in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-compiler, angular-ivy

**Problem:**

I am setting up lazy loading for non-routed module in angular. At version 7 I used `NgModuleFactoryLoader` and it's function `load` to lazy load module and get first entry point to the module (service in out case)

```
this.loader.load('path-to-module')
  .then(factory => {
    const module = factory.create(this._injector);
    return module.injector.get(EntryService);
  });
```

But in Angular 8 `NgModuleFactoryLoader` is deprecated so instead I have to load module in that way:

```
import('path-to-module')
  .then(m => m.MyModule)
  .then(myModule => {
    ...
});
```

The problem here that I can not retrieve factory and get provider here in a new lazy loading (one of ideas of IVY - no factories).

**What I have already tried:**

First solution (work only with JIT compiler which is not suits us as I am using AOT compiler for prod)

```
import('path-to-module')
  .then(m => m.MyModule)
  .then(myModule => {
    return this._compiler.compileModuleAsync(myModule)
      .then(factory => {
        const module = factory.create(this._injector);
        return module.injector.get(EntryService);
      });
});
```

Second solution (dirty and not fully checked. It is using `ngInjectorDef` which is new feature of IVY and has no any described API yet):

```
import('path-to-module')
  .then(m => m.MyModule)
  .then(myModule => {
    const providers = myModule['ngInjectorDef'].providers; // Array<Providers>
    ... find EntryService in providers
});
```

`ngInjectorDef` - is a static module class property which is added by angular and has properties factory, providers and imports.

**Sources:**

- https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093 (lazy loading non routable modules till angular 8)
- https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2018/02/19/angular-ivy/ (IVY preview - see section `No NgFactory file anymore`)
- https://blog.angularindepth.com/automatically-upgrade-lazy-loaded-angular-modules-for-ivy-e760872e6084 (Describes differences between lazy loading in Angular < 8 and Angular 8. Important section - From NgModule to NgModuleFactory with the AOT Compiler, what is basically my problem now)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say that accessing the `ngInjectorDef` property is a "dirty hack". Yes, it is not documented anywhere because, as Igor Minar said, Ivy is opt-in preview in Angular 8. But a lot of private functions were already mentioned in some articles of Viktor Savkin, for example `directiveInject`.

You should not search for your service in the `providers` property. Imagine that there are 20+ providers and also the `EntryService` name will be minified in the production to something like `t` or `k`.

If you use Ivy - there is a private function called `createInjector`, that accepts module constructor as an argument.

```js
@Injectable()
export class EntryService {
  public logFromEntryService(): void {
    console.log('Logging from EntryService...');
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [EntryService]
})
export class EntryModule {
  public static getEntryService: () => EntryService = null;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    EntryModule.getEntryService = () => injector.get(EntryService);
  }
}
```

Assume you've got such code, let's use a dynamic import to load this `EntryModule`:

```js
import { ɵcreateInjector as createInjector } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.loadEntryModule();
  }

  private async loadEntryModule(): Promise<void> {
    const { EntryModule } = await import('./entry.module');
    createInjector(EntryModule, this.injector);
    EntryModule.getEntryService().logFromEntryService();
  }
}
```

`createInjector` is used for instantiating `EntryModule`, after instanting - the `getEntryService` static method doesn't equal `null`.

We could also expose the `injector` property, like:

```js
public static injector: Injector = null;

constructor(injector: Injector) {
  EntryModule.injector = injector;
}
```

This might be treated as a service locator, which is kind of anti-pattern. But up to you!

Comment: Thanks for such a big and great answer! I already tried what you described, but when I call createInjector for imported module - I have an error `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for...` for any providers and declarations inside imported module.
Should I enable IVY for this feature to work? `"angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": true},`

Comment: Sure, you should, this only works with Ivy, you just mentioned in your question that you're using Ivy :D

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot one more time. For now we are just preparing for moving to IVY. So once we will use that, I will be able to use the solution :)

Comment: @JackHudzenko probably... 